# Using same timestamp value in 3 columns via query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following query where I am inserting timestamp value in 3 different columns. I am having to repeat the timezone method thrice due to this. Is there a way to only use the method once and use the same value for all 3 columns?

This is achievable via code. But trying to to see if I can do it purely via just the SQL query.

Current working SQL query where I am repeating timezone('PST', now()) thrice.

```
INSERT INTO user(name, created_ts, updated_ts, test_ts) 
VALUES ('Daniel', timezone('PST', now(), timezone('PST', now(), timezone('PST', now())
```

Please advice. Thanks.

Comment: That's not working SQL, and I don't see the point.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Just trying not to repeat the method plus the possiblity for the time to differ between the 3 cos I called now() thrice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
INSERT INTO user(name, created_ts, updated_ts, test_ts) 
select 'Daniel', ts, ts, ts
from ( 
  values ( timezone('PST', now()) )
) as t(ts);
```

---

However, from the comments to the question:

> *the possiblity for the time to differ between the 3 cos I called now() thrice*

`now()` will return a constant value throughout a transaction. There is no need for such a micro-optimization if it's just for that.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying on the now(). Your solution works but from personal preference find this more unreadable compared to the original solution. Might stick with what I have but ew learnings from this nonetheless. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`now()` (or, equivalently, the standard SQL `current_timestamp`) are the timestamp from the start of the database transactions, so all three calls are guaranteed to return the same value.

In short, don't worry.

From [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TABLE):

> `now()` Current date and time (start of current transaction)